# change border color of an element inside the label when radio button is clicked with pure css

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I am trying to change a border color for a span element when the radio button is checked. But my code is not working.
Here's a simpler version of my code:

```css
.try-2 {
  border-left: 3px solid pink;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked .try-2 {
  border-left: 3px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="html-css" name="fav_language" value="HTML-CSS">
<label for="html-css">
  <span class="try-1">HTML</span>
  <span class="try-2">CSS</span>
</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="js" name="fav_language" value="JS">
<label for="js">JS</label><br>
```

Comment: `label input[type="radio"]` selects any input that's a descendant of a label, and you have none

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is, that `span` is not the sibling of the input. The sibling of the input is the `label`. You have to change your selector to: `input[type="radio"]:checked ~ label span`

```css
.try-2 {
  border-left: 3px solid pink;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked ~ label span {
  border-left: 3px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="html-css" name="fav_language" value="HTML-CSS">
<label for="html-css">
  <span class="try-1">HTML</span>
  <span class="try-2">CSS</span>
</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="js" name="fav_language" value="JS">
<label for="js">JS</label><br>
```